# I wanted to plot different charts for different dates in python in data set, I tried using matplotlib but it didn't work

Tags: python

I wanted to plot separate charts for each days for the range of data using bar graphs. Is there a way to do this.

```
DATE  Maximum  Minimum    Average  Mode
0  2022-01-06     25.0     17.5  20.500000  20.0
1  2022-01-07     30.5     15.5  20.686641  17.5
2  2022-01-08     30.5     18.0  21.298713  19.0
3  2022-01-09     29.5     16.5  20.925900  18.0
4  2022-01-10     30.0     17.5  21.830637  19.5
5  2022-01-11     26.5     18.0  21.325852  19.0
6  2022-01-12     29.0     18.0  21.499826  20.0
7  2022-01-13     30.5     18.0  21.346468  19.5
```

Comment: Looking at your data, each day has only one data point under each column. So do you want to plot just one point per day?... Can you also post what you have tried?

Comment: Please share the code you wrote that is creating an error